# How to write a curried method in C#?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, currying

The following code will run and print `11`

```
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Func<int, int, int> _Add = (x,y) => x + y;
    var Add = Curry(_Add);
    int z = Add (5) (6);
    Console.WriteLine(z); // 11
  }

  public static Func<T1, Func<T2, T3>> Curry<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, T2, T3> f) {
    return x => y => f(x, y);
  }
}
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to define the curried method on the class rather than locally

```
public static ... Add(...) { /* define curried form using Curry helper */
  return f(x, y); 
}
```

It should be callable like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  Add (5) (6); // => should return 11
}
```

If I have a lot of methods that I want curried, it would be nice to use a helper function to define them. Writing each one by hand will be too tiring. Anyway, I can't figure out the proper syntax for this. Please help. I'm a C# noob.

Comment: What do you mean 'Writing each one by hand will be too tiring' - they have to be declared somewhere...?

Comment: by the way what is the main benefit you are getting from this style of coding (currying) over the traditional style?  Are you using just operator functions like add or also more complex functions?

Answer (score 3):

You can just return a `Func<int, int>` from `Add`:

```
public static Func<int, int> Add(int x) { 
    return y => x + y;
}
```

or declare it as a property:

```
public static Func<int, Func<int, int>> Add
{
    get { return x => y => x + y; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your original curry a constructor can initialize the functions.  How flexible do you need your types to be?

```
public static class Test
{
    static Test()
    {
        Add = Curry<int,int,int>((x, y) => x+y);
        Multiply = Curry<int,int,int>((x, y) => x*y);
    }

    public static Func<int, Func<int, int>> Add { get; }
    public static Func<int, Func<int, int>> Multiply { get; }

    public static Func<T1, Func<T2, T3>> Curry<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, T2, T3> f) {
      return x => y => f(x, y);
    }
}
```

For just a bunch of method implementations they could be contained like this

```
public static class Test
{
    public static Func<int, Func<int, int>> Add => x => y => x + y;
    public static Func<int, Func<int, int>> Multiply => x => y => x * y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To curry the function you first need to pass a function to a function.

```
void Main()
{
    var test = Add(() => 5)(6);
    test.Dump();
}

public Func<int, int> Add(Func<int> a)
{
    return (x) => x + a();
}

//returns 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want currying and partial-application, currying becomes quite inefficient when you have many parameters.  When I did it I implemented a ton of static methods called `curry` and `par` that can handle up to 10 parameters and partially apply N values.

Here's an example for 4 parameters:

```
public static Func<T1, Func<T2, Func<T3, Func<T4, R>>>> curry<T1, T2, T3, T4, R>(Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, R> f) =>
        (T1 a) => (T2 b) => (T3 c) => (T4 d) => f(a, b, c, d);
```

It quickly ends up with many nested delegates.  And this is where partial application comes in:

```
public static Func<T4, R> par<T1, T2, T3, T4, R>(Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, R> func, T1 a, T2 b, T3 c) =>
        (T4 d) => func(a, b, c, d);
```

To use the curyring example above you would do:

```
var f = curry(func);
var r = f(1)(2)(3)(4);
```

But often partial application is what you want:

```
var f = par(1,2,3);
var r = f(4);
```

This is fully implemented in my C# functional library: [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext)

[Currying source](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/Prelude_Curry.cs)

[Partial application source](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/Prelude_PartialApplication.cs)

You can take those source files as-is, there's no external dependencies.

In your example you could declare a the `Add` method thus:

```
class Test
{
    public static readonly Func<int, Func<int, int>> Add => x => y => x + y;
}
```

Or the classic way and use the `curry` function:

```
class Test
{
    public static readonly int Add(int x, int y) => x + y;
}

var add = curry(Test.Add);
var r = add(1)(2);
```

Or partially apply:

```
class Test
{
    public static int Add(int x, int y) => x + y;
}

var addOne = par(Test.Add, 1);
var r = addOne(2);
```